# How to login before management command

Tags: django, django-management-command

I have a bunch of code where I do things with the current user( setting created_by field , sending mail on creation of certain records).

But as far as I know you don't have a logged in user in your management command, so the question is, how can I run management commands as a valid logged in user?

Comment: This is unanswerable without seeing some code. Where are these "things" getting the current user from? If it's from the request, you have a deeper problem which is that a management command does not involve a request; which should be making you think of refactoring to extract common code so that you can pass a user explicitly.

Comment: I just django-crum, to get the current user. I have code regarding user in my models.py

Comment: Well, now you know exactly why that functionality is not supported in core Django. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: I know it is not encouraged to use such tool. I will be think over how to handle it differently.

Comment: Note though that that package has an [`impersonate`](https://pythonhosted.org/django-crum/#impersonate-user-none) context manager which surely does what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel.